# How to take ownership of a new internal drive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ntfs, uac

I have installed a new internal drive to replace an existing one. I formatted it as NTFS.

My issue is that every time I copy something I get a UAC elevation prompt.

As a long time Mac/Linux user, I'm not really sure what to do.

How can I fix this with these three things in mind?

1. Easily manage the drive (create files and folders, delete files and folders and etc) without UAC elevation (or turning off UAC elevation)
2. Permissions will need to survive a windows reinstall so I don't have to fix it again.
3. I don't really want to use the everyone group.

Comment: You're not really needing to "take ownership" to avoid UAC prompts as suggested by your title, but I didn't want to put words in your mouth so I've not changed it. But a better post title may be, "how to avoid UAC prompts on a new drive?"

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I am assuming that by taking ownership/full control of the drive, I should hopefully avoid UAC elevation.

Comment: Yes, that is what my answer confirms.

Answer (score 2):

> permissions will need to survive a windows reinstall so I don't have to fix it again.

This is the requirement that dictates the solution. If it weren't for this, the recommended way to maintain security without triggering UAC prompts would be to grant your own user account full control at the root of the drive. However, to survive a Windows reinstall, you must grant there Full Control permissions to a well-known security identity (i.e. one that is not unique to a particular installation of windows).

Therefore, granting the `Users` group Full Control at the root of the drive is the best way to accomplish what you're after.

If a drive already contains data, you will want to overwrite the permissions of child objects with these new permissions. Also, if you're not the owner of the existing objects, you may need to take ownership of them in order to successfully overwrite the existing permissions.

Comment: the drive is currently assigned as D and looking at some screens available when in the Security tab for the drive properties, Is it currrently owned by administrators. I checked the acct created by Windows and it's already part of administrator by default.

Comment: That's normal. Is this just an observation or are you asking a question?